# Random numbers from set Python

Tags: python, list, random, set

```
set_a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

I want to have 4 packages with 2 numbers randomly taken from `set_a`. Condition is that if a number is chosen, it cannot be taken anymore.

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
d = [7, 8]
```

I tried to achieve my goal with `random.sample` and list comparison but it didn't work out for me.

Next try was to remove the numbers from set with `set_a.discard()` and `set_a.remove()` which already have been chosen, but this didn't work either.

Comment: shuffle it as a list and take two numbers at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to shuffle the list and assign it to four variables:

```
from random import shuffle

set_a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

l = [*set_a]
shuffle(l)

a, b, c, d = zip(l[::2], l[1::2])
print(a, b, c, d, sep="\n")
```

Prints (for example):

```
(5, 1)
(7, 8)
(4, 2)
(6, 3)
```